# Interval notation for NumberLinePlot

Tags: plotting, custom-notation, traditional-form, intervals

Consider:

```
NumberLinePlot[Abs[3 - 4 x] < 2, x,
 PlotStyle -> {Thick, Blue, PointSize[Large]},
 Ticks -> {Range[0, 1.5, .25]}]
```

Which produces this image:

[image]

What's a simple way to produce interval notation in Traditional Form describing this solution, that is, $(0.25,1.25)$.

And how about for:

```
NumberLinePlot[Abs[2x-3]>1,{x,-2,5}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Via some formatting functions -- you'll have to write more to cover all cases:

```
ClearAll[intervalForm];
intervalForm[
   i : Less[x_Symbol, x2_?NumericQ] | 
     Greater[x2_?NumericQ, x_Symbol]] := 
  Interpretation[Row[{"(", -Infinity, ",", x2, ")"}], i];
intervalForm[
   i : Less[x1_?NumericQ, x_Symbol] | 
     Greater[x_Symbol, x1_?NumericQ]] := 
  Interpretation[Row[{"(", x1, ",", Infinity, ")"}], i];
intervalForm[
   i : Inequality[x1_?NumericQ, Less, x_Symbol, Less, x2_?NumericQ] | 
     Inequality[x2_?NumericQ, Greater, x_Symbol, Greater, 
      x1_?NumericQ] | Less[x1_?NumericQ, x_Symbol, x2_?NumericQ] | 
     Greater[x2_?NumericQ, x_Symbol, x1_?NumericQ]] := 
  Interpretation[Row[{"(", x1, ",", x2, ")"}], i];
```

Examples:

```
intervalForm@ N@ Reduce[Abs[3 - 4 x] < 2, x, Reals]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
intervalForm /@ Reduce[Abs[2 x - 3] > 1, x, Reals]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Alternatively, this last example can also be done like this:

```
$ineqPat = Less | Greater | LessEqual | GreaterEqual | Inequality;  (*$*)
Reduce[Abs[2 x - 3] > 1, x, Reals] /. i : $ineqPat[__] :> intervalForm[i]
```

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly interval notation but `Reduce` can give you clear notation of intervals.

```
Reduce[Abs[3 - 4 x] < 2, x ∈ Reals]
Reduce[Abs[2 x - 3] > 1, x ∈ Reals]
```

> 1/4 < x < 5/4
>
> x < 1 || x > 2